ffmpeg — маркировка четных кадров
Я использую эту команду для маркировки каждого кадра зеленой меткой:
ffmpeg -i "F:\Avatar\film3\film.mp4" -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=5:h=3:color=green:t=fill" "F:\Avatar\film3\output_with_markers3.mov"

Подскажите, как мне сделать аналогичную маркировку, но только для каждого четного кадра? нечетные кадры должны при этом остаться без маркировки.
